# Symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 - Flash Builder for Windows / iOS Native Extension

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, flash-builder, air-native-extension

I'm attempting to run the example project for this Adobe Native Extension '[SongPickerANE](https://github.com/richpixel/SongPickerANE)' from Flash Builder on Windows onto an iOS device. I've run it successfully on the same device (and iOS Simulator) from Flash Builder on my Mac with AIR SDK 3.4, but it failed to run with 3.4 on Windows, as it couldn't get access to the required iOS SDK (6.1).

So, I've updated my AIR SDK on my windows machine, first to 3.5, and now to the current version 3.9, which seemed to sort out the iOS SDK issues I was having, but both failed to run with the following error:

```
java.lang.Exception: 
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_objc_setProperty_nonatomic", referenced from:
      -[SongPickerHelper setPickedItem:] in libcom.newpixel.air.nativeextensions.SongPicker.a(SongPickerHelper.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
Compilation failed while executing : ld64
```

From what I remember of it in the dim, distant past of my iOS development, this is some sort of XCode linking / Build Settings / Phases error? So to fix it, will I have to edit and recompile the ANE, or is there anything I can set in the Flash Builder project which uses the ANE to fix it?

If it requires recompiling the ANE, any tips / advice on where to start would be appreciated, as I've so far managed to avoid having anything to do with them, and I do find them slightly terrifying.

Many thanks in advance.